# If an infinite group acts freely on two sets then the sets are bijective via an action preserving bijection?

Tags: group-theory, set-theory, group-actions, infinite-groups

Let $G$ be an infinite group. Let $X,Y$ be two sets on which $G$ acts freely.

(An action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ is called free iff $G_x:=\{g\in G : gx=x\}$ is singleton for every $x\in X$ ).

Then how to show that there is a bijection $f: X \to Y$ such that $f(gx)=gf(x), \forall g\in G, \forall x\in X$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without additional assumptions, the claim is false: e.g. the group $\mathbb{Z}$ acts freely on both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ by translation, but there is no bijection between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ at all.

---

If we assume that additionally the action of $G$ is *transitive*, then the result is true: if $G$ acts freely and transitively on $X$ and $Y$, then there is an action-preserving bijection between $X$ and $Y$.

To prove this, fix $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, and consider the map $$gx\mapsto gy.$$ This map:

- Is well-defined, by freeness of the group action on $X$ ($g_1x=g_2x\iff g_1=g_2$).
- Is defined on all of $X$, by the transitivity of the group action on $X$.
- Is a surjection, by the transitivity of the group action on $Y$.
- Is an injection, by the freeness of the group action on $Y$.

(A useful word to introduce at this point is ["torsor"](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/torsors.html).)

---

Alternatively, the following fact is easy to prove:

> Suppose $G$ acts freely on $X, Y$. Then there is an action-preserving bijection between $X$ and $Y$ iff the number of orbits is the same.

Basically, since the action is free each orbit "looks like" a copy of $G$ itself; any two orbits are therefore in action-preserving bijection, and so the only remaining possible obstacle is their number.

Note that the number of orbits can't be determined from cardinality alone: e.g. $\mathbb{Z}$ acting on $\mathbb{Z}$ by translation has one orbit, but $\mathbb{Z}$ acting on $\mathbb{Q}$ by translation has infinitely many orbits.

Note that **transitivity is exactly the property of having a single orbit**, so this is a generalization of the previous observation.

Comment: What if we know $X,Y$ have the same cardinality ? Does my claim follow then ?

Comment: @users Still no - think about $\mathbb{Z}$ acting on $\mathbb{Z}$ and on $\mathbb{Q}$ by translation. The former action has a single orbit, the latter action has infinitely many orbits, and any action-preserving bijection has to preserve the number of orbits.

Comment: I think , if $X,Y$ have the same cardinality and $|X| > |G|\ge \aleph_0$, then my claim is true

Comment: @users Yes, because in that case the number of orbits must be equal. Indeed, you don't even need the requirement that $G$ be infinite: just that $X, Y$ be infinite, have the same cardinality, and have cardinality $>\vert G\vert$.

Comment: Could you please write down a detailed proof of this here or at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2756360/if-an-infinite-group-g-acts-freely-on-two-sets-of-same-cardinality-g-th ? It would be very helpful for me ... thanks